# WSO2 MDM Android Agent issue

Tags: android, wso2, agent, mdm

I was able to succesfully build and export the Android app in Eclipse after entering the server IP address in the CommonUtilities.java file.

This apk is downloaded, installed and run on the mobile android device with success.
But now when I enter all necessary data for first registration of the app and choose 'Register', I get a message saying : 'Authentication failed due to a conenction failure do you want to try again?'

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you replace your ServerUtilities.java with our latest [version](https://github.com/wso2-dev/emm-agent-android/blob/master/src/org/wso2/emm/agent/utils/ServerUtilities.java) ? And test it with HTTP and if it works, then try with HTTPs also. In case the HTTP works and HTTP not, then you have to check your BKS and put a valid BKS there.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. This indeed seems to have solved this issue.
Now I get an authentication error, probably since the user/pwd combination is not right, even though I also tried with default admin@admin.com user (over HTTP).

Comment: Now check your Log and see whether your server receives the request from the mobile device (username and password). If not, please check your IP configurations in the Agent app and check for the credentials in the carbon admin. Or else you can create a new user using our MDM console and try authenticate using that user account.

Comment: Thanks for the info. A restart of the MDM service solved my problem (DB connections were down). Everything is working now. Thanks for all the assistance during the last weeks!

Answer (score 2):

This message is displayed when there is a connection failure or the server SSL certificate is not trusted. Connection between the Android agent app and the EMM server is through https and if you are using a self signed certificate then you need to put it in the Agent project in Eclipse and export the Android app.
Please refer the [Android Client Configuration](http://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/Android+Client+Configurations) to create the BKS and add it to your android project.

Similar question was asked in [Github of MDM-Android-Agent](https://github.com/wso2/MDM-Android-Agent/issues/1)

Comment: Thank you for the info.
I think it has to do with the fact that I didn't add my personal BKS file to the res/raw directory. So I used the Eclipse-generated keystore file (saved as .bks) which I used to initially build and export the MDM Agent project, but this still gives the same result as before on my mobile device. So I think I must still be doing sth wrong, right?
Do I need to follow the openssl-based tutorial on the wso2 manual to generate a valid bks or are there easier ways?

Comment: You can follow the openssl-based tutorieal in the wso2 manual where you will be generating the CA and the SSL. The CA needs to be converted to the BKS format and the SSL needs to be imported to the jks files as mentioned in the [document](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/iOS+Server+Configurations).

Comment: Thanks.
I used openssl to create all p12's i needed, but....when using the keytool I succesfully imported them into the wso2carbon.jks and the client-truststore.jks, but it keeps ons failing to import into the wso2mobilemdm.jks keystore. I always get the message : "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format". When I specify the keystore type to be jks I get the same error, when I specify as PKCS12 I get an error about the length of the file.
Am I doing sth wrong? I googled and tried a lot but it seems that the wso2mobilemdm.jks file is corrupt.

Comment: Delete the existing wso2mobilemdm.jks and execute the command to import the p12 into wso2mobilemdm.jks.

Answer (score 1):

Android expects your keystore to be in Bouncy Castle (BKS) format. In the docs it has linked to a iOS keystore generation code in OpenSSL since this phase also needs to be done inorder to configure the EMM. If you are only configuring the Android make sure the keystore file is in BKS format. One way to do is to generate a JKS file by following the commands in the documentation using OpenSSL and convert it to BKS format. You may use [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Comment: Ok, I did all this, but now I still got the same issue as my initial question. Does anybody have any ideas what might be wrong? Can I sent my client code to someone for a review? I am completely clueless...

Comment: I think you may have the issues with the SSL settings. What you can do is for now just forget about the https and work on http. If its working fine for http then you can configure it to work in https later. To work with http you dont need to deal with the bks file. Just change the android code configurations.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said and still I cannot connect to the server..Still got the Connection failure message.
My code is like this:
public static String SERVER_IP = "78.47.152.125";
 public static String SERVER_PORT = "9763";
 public static String SERVER_PROTOCOL = "http://";
 public static String SERVER_APP_ENDPOINT = "/mdm/api/";
 public static String SERVER_URL = SERVER_PROTOCOL+SERVER_IP+":"+SERVER_PORT+SERVER_APP_ENDPOINT;
    public static final String TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD = "MyPassWord";

Comment: And I removed the contents of the /res/raw/emm.truststore.bks file. I build the apk, sign it with a self-signed certificate, put it on the server folder for download and download and install on my mobile.
Then I just launch and accept the proposed IP address, on the next screen I enter my emailaddress that's registered on the MDM server, I enter 'a' password, choose BYOD or COPE and then Register. Is this ok?

Comment: If you are using http you dont need to configure bks. If you enter the ip address that's it. The way you install the app is upon getting an email from the EMM. You have to login to EMM and add a user with the email address where you get the download link. After that you can use that credentials for login. If you dont want to do that you may login with default admin username passwords which is admin@admin.com/admin for testing purposes to ensure that the client is working.

Comment: Did it, but still the same issue. Issue pops up so quickly that I don't think it even made a connection to the server....
I also tried with 3G and Wifi, but both fail.
Server is reachable through both HTTPS and HTTP. I even get an error message when I go to http(s)://{home}:9763/mdm/api/users/authenticate
So really must be related to client app...but what.....?

Comment: If its https the port number is 9443. If its http the port number is 9763. Can you check that?

Comment: Can you share your Android agent project in the EMM developer list?

Comment: Hello Dilshan, thanks a lot for all the efforts and replies.
Can you tell me where exactly I can find the EMM developer list?

Comment: or else host this in a public IP so I will have a look

Comment: hi, you can download the the android agent from this location:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9M5bjCHVklmRUU4SGVTNTVqY0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Dilshan, were you able to have a look at my client code already? Found anything that's not right?

Comment: Yes we are going through it.

Comment: Please look at the Kasuns answer below. It will solve your issue.